# Why my cast on user def type doesnt work?

Tags: ocaml

```
type card = int

type game = { dimension : int; p1 : card list; }

let fn (_dimension : int) (p1 : card list) : bool =
  (int)p1 = (int)_dimension * 2
```

I want to check that p1 is exactly twice the size of dimension.

Comment: I don't think a cast like that would make sense even in PHP! What you want is the 'List.length' function.

Comment: let x = List.length _p1
  _dimension == (int) x*2
but still cant use it as integer.

Comment: There is no valid OCaml expression of the form `(int) expr`. There's no such thing as "casting" in OCaml. (You can define a function named `int` if you like, but that is a separate matter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't look very much like OCaml code, so it's difficult to know how to help :-)

There is no operation in OCaml to change the type of a value. That wouldn't make sense in a strongly typed language. There are some things you can do with types, but "casting" isn't one of them.

So, there is no valid expression that looks like `(int) expr`. As @glennsl points out, there is a function that returns the length of a list. If that's what you're trying to calculate, you can use `List.length _dimension`. The other occurrences of `(int)` you can just remove. They aren't valid OCaml.

Your definition of `fn` doesn't use the type `game` anywhere, so the definition of `game` is unnecessary. However it makes me worry that you're expecting the definition to have an effect.

If you leave out all the type ascriptions in your definition of `fn` the compiler will deduce the most general type for your function. This means you can call it with any list to check its length. That would be more idiomatic in OCaml. I.e., you don't need to specify that `p1` is a list of cards. The function makes sense for any list.